# Is there a way to use sshfs for a machine "two jumps away"?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

For transferring files between two Linux machines I always felt more comfortable using the graphical file managers such as Nautilus, which offer the option to connect to a remote machine via SSH. However today I need to transfer files to a machine I cannot access directly -- I need to first SSH into a certain server and then do another SSH into my final destination. Is there still a way to do a GUI-friendly file transfer here or should I just fall back to good-old command-line scp this time?

Comment: Does the intermediate server allow tunnels?

Comment: I have no idea, but feel free to answer assuming they do :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Supposing the intermediate host is allowing port forwarding, you can do half of the work using command line and finish graphically as usual:

```
sshfs -o ssh_command='ssh -J firstuser@firsthost' finaluser@finalhost:directory localdirectory
```

or actually, since `-o ProxyJump` (which is the same as `-J` for `ssh`) is accepted directly by `sshfs` (which will then provide it to its `ssh` backend), this can be rewritten as:

```
sshfs -o ProxyJump=firstuser@firsthost finaluser@finalhost:directory localdirectory
```

This will instruct sshfs to run its ssh backend (itself running the sftp subsystem in the end) with an additional [`ProxyJump`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#ProxyJump) option, which itself will transparently forward the SSH connection to the destination.

This is equivalent to adding instead in `$HOME/.ssh/config`:

```
Host finalhost
    ProxyJump firstuser@firsthost
```

and just run `sshfs finaluser@finalhost:directory localdirectory`, or else you can also put the above two lines in a file and use the `-F` option of `sshfs` with this file.

Now your directory `localdirectory` is usable with Nautilus or any other tool, GUI or not (but usually limited to the user running `sshfs`, as usual).

It's quite possible that having this option in `$HOME/.ssh/config` will allow your GUI tool to transparently work as usual to mount the directory, thus not needing CLI anymore. I couldn't test this.

Comment: Using `-o ProxyJump=firstuser@firsthost` option is also possible, without the need to edit config files.