# How to bring back the files from a remote server (initially accessed through 2 step login) back to our local computer?

Tags: ssh, scp, file-server

For research purposes, I use the University server.

The server login is a two-step process.

First, I type

```
ssh -p 44  linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk
```

(Altered for security reason)

Then the password is prompted. I type the credential

Then I type

```
ssh linuxuser@10.567.96.303
```

Then the password is prompted. I type the credential

Now if I have to transfer a file (say a pdf file namely `first.pdf`) to the working directory I use the following code

```
scp - P 44 first.pdf linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk:~/

scp first.pdf linuxuser@10.567.96.303:~/
```

***Until here it is clear*** My doubt begins after this

1. If I have to ***bring back*** the `first.pdf` ***from the final working directory to the local machine. (working computer).***

***How to do it?***

2. I was able to access the intermediate directory (linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk:~/) through `Filezilla`. But I was not able to access the final main directory through Filezilla. I tried through other software such as `winscp` neither it worked.
   The GUI software generally has a single tab for typing username and password. But here I have 2 step login process. Hence the whole confusion.

***How to access the final working directory through a GUI software.***

Comment: Related: [How can I download a file from a host I can only SSH to through another host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537319/315749), [Transferring files between a server and a PC through another server (who was size limitations)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393344/315749), [Is there a way to use sshfs for a machine “two jumps away”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495845/315749).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rsync command can help you with:

`rsync -av -e "ssh -p 44 linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk" linuxuser@10.567.96.303:~/first.pdf ./`

The server `linuxuser@10.567.96.303` will be used as a proxy to reach the file on remote host. The file `first.pdf` will be copied on your local machine.

Comment: Are you sure about your command's syntax? I get an error (too long for reporting it here in a comment), while `rsync -av -e "ssh -J linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk:44 linuxuser@10.567.96.303" :~/first.pdf ./` works. Also, I think the "proxy" in the question would be `linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk`.

Comment: @maruscya I got the following error code on using your codes ```rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(235) [Receiver=3.1.2]```

Comment: @fra-san please post your comment as an answer. It really worked great. I was not able to find the answer easily in any forum, so it would be greatly beneficial to have it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @fra-san is there a way to access the same folder using a GUI

Comment: @fra-san is there a way to transfer the file to the final working directory in a single step

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M I'm not fond of posting answers differing from existing answers on syntax details only. Better to have the existing answers improved ;-) Here, it should be enough to just change `-p 44 linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk` to `-J linuxuser@jackbio-oopd.res.uk:44`. Note that `--debug=CMD` (if your version of rsync supports it) is very handy to debug command line errors.

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP actually supports connecting via an SSH [jump server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server).

Just specify connection data for your intermediate server on the [Tunnel page of the advanced site settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

See also WinSCP guide for [Connecting to FTP/SFTP server which can be accessed via another server only](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_tunnel).

---

For Linux command-line solutions, see:
[How can I download a file from a host I can only SSH to through another host?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/537319/119732#537328)

Comment: WinSCP worked absolutely abliss.